# SharePoint 2019: filter users and groups in People Picker with ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, filter, active-directory, people-picker

We are currently trying to filter the *People Picker* in *SharePoint 2019* for users and groups, but we have a little bit of trouble.

Currently, we have the following filter:

```
(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(sn=svc*)(!givenName=*)))

// or more clearly

(&
    (objectCategory=person)
    (objectClass=user)
    (|
        (sn=svc*)
        (!givenName=*)
    )
)
```

This filter is a little bit strange, but it works as expected. More precisely, because we have *ADFS* and *NTLM* authentication set up for our *WebApplication*, we have every account twice. This filter sets the *People Picker* to display *UPN* and *service accounts* only.

However, now, we would also like to filter every group starting with "*LD*". So, we tried, among many other things, the following filter:

```
(|(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(sn=svc*)(!givenName=*)))(&(objectCategory=group)(!cn=LD*)))

// or more clearly

(|
    (&
        (objectCategory=person)
        (objectClass=user)
        (|
            (sn=svc*)
            (!givenName=*)
        )
    )
    (&
        (objectCategory=group)
        (!cn=LD*)
    )
)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. We tried to play with `displayName`, `name` and `mail` without success. The first part of the filter works fine, but the second part is ignored. We also tried to use `objectCategory=CN=Group,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=Domain,DC=com` instead of `objectCategory=group` and `objectClass=group`, without more chance.

We use the following commands to apply filtering:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication https://some.sharepoint.farm.com
$webApp.PeoplePickerSettings.ActiveDirectoryCustomFilter = "SUPER AWESOME FILTER"
$webApp.Update()
iisreset

// and a good clear cache for our browser
```

The solution is probably right under our noses, but we can not figure this problem out.

Can anyone kindly give us a hand on this?

Many thanks in advance!